# get number of likes of photo shared from app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

i share a photo using facebook sdk in this way:

```
File file = new File("imagePath");

Request photoRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(session, file, new Callback() {            
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        if(response.getError()==null){
            try {
               String id = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().get("id").toString();
              //store id
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }           
});
photoRequest.getParameters().putString("message", "xxx");
photoRequest.executeAsync();
```

Now i want to get likes on that id.
I try in this way:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("id", id); // this is the id stored before
bundle.putString("fields", "likes");
Request request = new Request(session, "search", bundle, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
            //Obj is always -> {"data":[]}
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
});
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

What facebook API gets is always `{"data":[]}`.

I use this permission:

```
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(act, "publish_actions","user_photos","user_status"));
```

What could be the problem??
Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: That's a stupid question- but I want to ask whether there are likes in the post? I mean you make sure there are some likes i the post. Also, please check the same process with the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and let me know the results

Comment: So you are saying me that if i share a picture on fb i can't get user's like count on it because picture on fb doesn't have likes? o.O

Comment: Obviously. If there are no likes how can you get likes from graph api?

Comment: But i can add like to the photo i share using cose upon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Bundle params = new Bundle();
String fql    = "SELECT like_info,src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id=\""+shared.getId()+"\"";
params.putString("q", fql);
Request request = new Request(session, "/fql",params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {      
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        String message = "Foto cancellata";
        try {
            JSONObject resp = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
            JSONArray  data = resp.getJSONArray("data");
            if(data.length()>0){
                JSONObject like_info = data.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("like_info");
                String src           = data.getJSONObject(0).getString("src_big");
                if(!image.exists()){
                    aq.id(shared_image).image(src);
                }                   
                int count = like_info.getInt("like_count");
            }else{
               //PICTURE HAS BEEN DELETED
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
});
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```